# Изменение порядка строк в таблице на React'е

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сортировка

Есть таблица на React'е, как можно реализовать изменение порядка строк в ней, поменять третью на первую и т.п.?

Ничего не приходит на ум, не судите, если глупый вопрос, не давно начал изучать, спасибо за помощь.

[image: Таблица]

Comment: лучше воспользоваться готовым плагином. Их куча. Если хотите делать кастомную, то читайте о реализации drag and drop компонентов!

Answer (score 3):

Тут все достаточно просто, если нужно "перевернуть" массив целиком, то то можно воспользоваться методом [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), а для более детальной сортировки подойдет метод [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
const initialState = [
  {id: 1, name: "name1", type: "main", color: "#000"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", type: "background", color: "#000"},
  {id: 3, name: "name3", type: "title", color: "#000"}
]

const [list, setList] = useState(initialState)

const handleSort = () => {
  const sorted = [...list].reverse()
  // const sorted = [...list].sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
  setList(sorted)
}

// [
//   { id: 3, name: "name3", type: "title", color: "#000" },
//   { id: 2, name: "name2", type: "background", color: "#000" },
//   { id: 1, name: "name1", type: "main", color: "#000" }
// ]
```